# Using a function on a data.frame or specific cols of a df with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I want to apply the winsorize function/or any other function on a dataframe (or selected columns of a dataframe) and not change the structure of that dataframe. I don't understand what I am doing wrong:

```
library(plm)     # required for dataset Grunfeld
library(plyr)    
library(robustHD) # with winsorize function
data(Grunfeld)
head(Grunfeld)

Grunfeld.w<-ddply(Grunfeld, c("year"), function(df) winsorize(df))

# or on specific cols: 
Grunfeld.w2<- ddply(Grunfeld, c("year"), function(df) 
                    c(winsorize(df$inv),winsorize(df$capital)))
```

The question is not related to the specific winsorize function but to any function that returns an output in the exact same structure (unlike mean() or other functions).

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  The first 10 columns after the `year` column in `Grunfeld.w2` corresponds to `inv`.  The next 10 columns (`V11` to `V20` would be the `capital`.  You could possibly check the output of

     `lapply(with(Grunfeld, split(inv, year)), winsorize);
     lapply(with(Grunfeld, split(capital, year)), winsorize);`

with that of `Grunfeld.w2`

Comment: This is driving me nuts as i cant code the simplest things... I think your suggestion is performing the winsorization accordingly, but it somehow messes up the structure of the dataframe. It was 200 observations (10 firms à 20 years over 5 variables (including firm id and year id). Somehow your code produces an output of 10 observations (firms) and 20 variables (years).